# JavaScript/Jquery Auto Generate Employee Id based on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm generating the `empId` using Servlet but my boss wants that when the user is typing, he will see the `empId` instantly based on what he inputs. And I'm not really familiar with JavaScript or JQuery, but I think it's the right tool to do this. Please help?

`empId` contains the first character in the first name, middle name, and surname plus a dash and the date of birth. Sample would be `JHD-01011990`.

Here's a simplified version of my HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="../profile/SaveProfile">
<label for="empId">Employee ID</label>                    
<input id="empId" name="empId" type="text" placeholder="FML-MMDDYYYY" required readonly>

<label for="title">Title</label>
<select id="title" name="title">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">Attorney</option>
    <option value="2">Doctor</option>
    <option value="3">Professor</option>
    <option value="4">Engineer</option>                                    
</select>                                

<label for="fname">Name</label>                     
<input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" placeholder="* First Name" required>
<input id="mname" name="mname" type="text" placeholder="* Middle Name" required>
<input id="lname" name="lname" type="text" placeholder="* Surname" required>
<input id="ename" name="ename" type="text" placeholder="Ext">

<label for="dob">* Date of Birth</label>
<input id="dob" name="dob" type="text" required>

<label for="doa">Date of Original Appointment</label>
<input id="doa" name="doa" type="text">

<button type="button">Close</button>
<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

And if needed, here's also my Java code for generating the `empId`

```
public String generateEmployeeId(String dateOfBirth, String firstName, String middleName, String surname) {        
    String[] birthdate = dateOfBirth.split("-");

    String empId = firstName.charAt(0) + middleName.charAt(0) + surname.charAt(0);
    empId += "-" + birthdate[1] + birthdate[2] + birthdate[0];

    return empId;
}
```

I'd like to post a sample screen shot of my form but I can't. Please tell me if you need it.

Thank you!

Comment: Please show your attempted Javascript code. We can't help you fix it if we don't see what you did. And we're not going to write it for you.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not really familiar with Javascript. That's why I'm asking for help if there's a way to convert my original code to do it.

Comment: We're here to **help**, not **do it for you**. If you need a programmer who knows Javascript, hire one.

Comment: @Barmar I do have a pseudocode in mind. I just don't know how to convert it in Javascript.

Comment: I'm note entirely sure about what you need, but you may Google: **AJAX**.

Comment: He doesn't need AJAX, it can be done directly in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#fname,#mname,#lname,#dob").keyup(function() {
        var birthdate = $("#dob").val().split('-');
        var fname = $("#fname").val();
        var lname = $("#lname").val();
        var mname = $("#mname").val();
        var empId = fname.charAt(0) + mname.charAt(0) + lname.charAt(0) + '-' + birthdate.join('');
        $("#empId").val(empId);
    });
});
```

It's a straightforward translation of your Java code, wrapped in a jQuery event handler, and using `.val()` to get the values from the input fields.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/gkvps3g1/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Beaten to it but still posting. This is same solution using jQuery

```
$(function(){
$( "#fname,#mname,#lname,#dob").keyup(function( event ) {
  if ( event.which == 13 ) {
     event.preventDefault();
  }

//you probably want to do a bit more checking of the DOB value - such as length etc., I am merely stripping all non numerics from it    
    id = $("#fname").val().charAt(0) + $("#mname").val().charAt(0) + $("#lname").val().charAt(0) + "-" + $("#dob").val().replace(/\D/g,'');

    $("#empId").val(id);

});

})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0h7nq8zq/)